# Google authorize popup gets stuck in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I am using [gapi](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/GettingStarted) client in a chrome extension to access Google Drive. First step is to authorize my app. I am using gapi.auth.authorize to start the authorization. After I authorize the app through a popup launched by gapi, the window never closes and gets stuck like shown in picture below. However authorization has succeeded in the background, because if I close window manually, I don't see the stuck popup next time. Can somebody point out what am I doing wrong?

**After I click 'Allow access' on authorization popup,**

[image]

**It then shows a blank popup which is stuck**

[image: Popup gets stuck]

**Code I am using**

```
function handleClientLoad(){
      gapi.client.setApiKey('My API key');
      window.setTimeout(checkAuthAuto, 1);
}


var checkAuthAuto = function () {
    console.log('checkAuthAuto');
    gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: 'My client id',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
        immediate: true
    }, handleAuthResult);
}



 function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        console.log('handleAuthResult');
        var authButton = document.getElementById('authorizeButton');
        var filePicker = document.getElementById('filePicker');
        var addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
        authButton.style.display = 'none';
        filePicker.style.display = 'none';
        addButton.style.display = 'none';
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          addButton.style.display = 'block';
          addButton.onclick = uploadFile;
          console.log('handleAuthResult:noerror');

        } else {
          // No access token could be retrieved, show the button to start the authorization flow.
          authButton.style.display = 'block';

          console.log('handleAuthResult:error');
          console.log(authResult);

          authButton.onclick = function() {
              console.log('authButton.onclick');
              gapi.client.setApiKey('My api key');
              gapi.auth.authorize({
                  client_id: 'My client id',
                  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
                  immediate: false
              }, handleAuthResult);
              return false;
          };
        }
}
```

Comment: I am also trying to make sure if I setup my API access correctly in google API console correctly. I have specified javascript origin - "chrome-extension://<extension id>" and left the redirect uri blank.

Comment: There is more discussion going on here - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-api-javascript-client/GuFxPzqQ9-0

Comment: Logged an issue for this on google code for gapi team,https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=74. Please upvote it.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am stuck with the same issue for days now. Chrome extension just won't close that popup no matter what. I have tried several javascript hacks but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

Even with chrome extensions, you can use chrome.identity and the popup closes just as we expect it.

Wrap chrome.identity.getAuthToken with a wrapper named gapi.auth.authorize.
Refer to: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/gapi-chrome-apps-lib/gapi-chrome-apps.js

The thing is that the current stable chrome 28 doesn't allow you to do that and you might as well version-check or wait for a while until the stable got this functionality. 
Still not sure though, doing this with extensions is okay even if i was able to do that...

Comment: Still not fixed in Chrome 33? I'm experiencing same issue.